# JSONP cross-domain request error

Tags: json, request, jsonp

Is there a way to get response status when doing JSONP request. I mean, can I see if it was a successful request 200 OK, or not found 404, or not available, etc. ?

ALTERNATIVELY: Maybe there is a way to try to load `.js` file using `new Image()` object, i.e. assuming it is an image and then see the response status? Or try to load even something completely different?

Is there any JavaScript cross-domain way to check if a resource is available or 404 unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

May be that library can be helpful:

https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp

Comment: As I understand, this library only tells you if it was `"success"`, `"error"`, or `"timeout"`, which is not specific enough in my case.

Comment: Right. But unfortunatelly it is the only data we can retrieve using JSONP... The problem with JSONP is that it places just a regular `<script>` tag to HTML and browsers do not provide access to status codes of loaded resources.